# Unable to re-create Gitlab user account

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce, createuser

I have removed the Gitlab user using rails command from Gitlab CE docker container as below

```
gitlab-rails console 
user = User.find_by_username('<username>')
user.delete
```

and now when i'm trying to create new account with same username. Gitlab 15.5 throws below error

```
A user, alias, or group already exists with that username.
```

I have cheked with rails command, if im trying to find user with username, it's giving **nil** so user doen't exists.
How do i create fresh account with same username in Gitlab CE 15.5 ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Rails command?

Comment: Hey @DMalan thanks for the response. have added gitlab-rails command that i had used to delete a user